# Can SAML Assertions Be Modified In Transit?

Tags: security, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

Is there anything to stop a user modifying a SAML assertion being sent to a service provider?

For example, if a SAML response identifies a user to the service provider by email address, is there anything in place within the assertion to stop someone modifying the it using something like Fiddler, and replacing their email address with someone in the same company who has a higher level of access in the service they are trying to access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assertions in your SAML response SHOULD be signed using a private/public key pair and [xmldsig](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/). If they are correctly signed, changing the contents of an assertion will invalidate the signature, and thus the assertion itself.

Now, if

- the service provider doesn't require a signature,
- or doesn't bother checking the validity of the signature,
- or the private key is compromised

then pretty much anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be modified, but even a slight change in the response(like adding a space) would fail the signature validation process at the service provider end (provided that SP is validating it as it should be done)